# Busy indicator is not displaying in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, busyindicator

Hi guys i want to display a `Busy Indicator` in my project.I am using a background worker thread but the problem is Busy Indicator is not displaying on the  screen i dont know what is the .The code is:

XAML is:

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    BusyContent="Please wait while the Access controller is configuring "
                    IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">

</xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

C# code is:

```
BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();

{
   _worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
      IsBusy = true;
      DiscoverConnectedDevices();
    };

            _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
                {
                    IsDiscoverButtonEnable = true;
                    IsBusy = false;
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;

                    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
                };
            ipmac = new ObservableCollection<IpMacAddressClass>();
        }
 public bool IsBusy
        {
            get
            {
                return _isBusy;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value!=_isBusy)
                {
                    IsBusy = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post your complete XAML code

Comment: I have edited the code and posted complete code

Comment: @CodeSnipper,do you have anyother controls in the xaml code, place your busy indicator outside the layout

Comment: i have placed it a parent grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting `IsBusy` within your setter, rather than `_isBusy`

Should be:

```
public bool IsBusy
{
    get
    {
        return _isBusy;
    }
    set
    {
        if(value!=_isBusy)
        {
            _isBusy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that was my eye sight mistake :)